# C# implementing abstract class method: I have to make a cast?

Tags: c#, casting, abstract-class

I have this two classes:

```
public abstract class Loop : Events
{ }

public class SimpleLoop : Loop
{
    public Sound sound;
    public SimpleLoop simple;
}
```

And I have this abstract class with an abstract method:

```
public abstract class AbstractParser
{
    public abstract Loop ParseLoop();
}
```

And this other class which extends the previous class and implement the abstract method:

```
public class Parser2 : AbstractParser
{
    public override Loop ParseLoop()
    {
        //not important stuff
        simpleLoop.simple = (SimpleLoop) ParseLoop();
        return simpleLoop;
    }
}
```

Now, my question is: there is a way to avoid the cast inside `simpleLoop.simple = (SimpleLoop) ParseLoop()` ?

Obviously I did not the entirely classes, so do not ask yourself what is the purpose of this mess :D Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered generics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Parser2 : AbstractParser
{
    public override Loop ParseLoop()
    {
        return ParseLoopImplementation();
    }

    private SimpleLoop ParseLoopImplementation()
    {
        //not important stuff
        simpleLoop.simple = ParseLoopImplementation();
        return simpleLoop;

    }
}
```

Note. Your code as is would produce a StackOverflowException as it is recursive on all paths.

Comment: Wow, so simpl to solve and I didn't think about it like an idiot! However, about StackOverflowException...maybe becuse in the end `//not important stuff` is VERY important stuff (and solves problems like the one that you wrote ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class SimpleLoopParser<T> : AbstractParser<T>
{
    protected override T ParseLoopImplementation()
    {
        simpleLoop.simple = //parse here;
        return simpleLoop;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractParser <T>
{
    public override T ParseLoop()
    {
        return ParseLoopImplementation();
    }

    protected abstract Loop ParseLoopImplementation();
}
```

And to call like this:

```
SimpleLoop simpleLoopParsed = new SimpleLoopParser<SimpleLoop>().ParseLoop();
```